# How to create Quarter parameter for SSRS Fetch xml when there is no Year or Quarter field

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, fetchxml

I'm new to SSRS and building an SSRS Quarterly Report using FetchXML for Dynamics365.
I need to create a parameter for Year and Quarter (Jan-Mar, Apr-Jun, Jul-Sep and Oct-Dec).There is no Year and Quarter field in the table, only the Case Received Date field. How should I accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: You will probable need to write a few `CASE WHEN THEN` statements into your query ...  IE `CASE WHEN received_date = 12 then 'Quarterly'`

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter and 'Specify Values' list in 'Available Values' like below:

```
Lable     Value
Jan-Mar    1 
Apr-Jun    2
Jul-Sep    3
Oct-Dec    4
```

Then in your query, you can use this value to compare against your date using `DATEPART(qq,[Case Received Date])`  which returns values 1 through 4 based on quarter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Subodh for your quick response. Do I need to create a new dataset also for Quarter to include DATEPART(qq,[Case Received Date])?

Comment: Also, looks like I can't use DATEPART in fetchxml.

Comment: I have no experience with FetchXML but can you not add a calculated field to the dataset from the dataset properties as I would imagine this would only be evaluated once the data has been retrieved. So, go to the dataset properties, then fields, then add then choose 'calculated'. I don't have an environment to test this with so it's purely a guess.

Comment: thanks @AlanSchofield, how should I link my parameter Quarter to the calculated field- Quarter?

Comment: Just add a filter to the dataset and filter your new 'calculated' quarter column using the value from your parameter

Comment: thanks @AlanSchofield, that worked. I'm using different datasets with different conditions for my report. One dataset query should show cases based on the Quarter selected, for example Jan-Mar which is working fine. Another dataset query should show me the cases that were received by end of last quarter. For example, when I select Jan-Mar, it should display cases received by end of last quarter which is Dec 31st, 2021. How can I accomplish this? I could use 'on-or-before' operator in my fetchxml but Quarter is not a field in the database, it's a calculated field in SSRS.

Comment: You need to start a new question. Make sure you include all relevant code and some sample data when you post the new question.